# WinForm DevExpress Xtragrid programmatically to check Specified check box column in grid view

Tags: c#, winforms, repository, devexpress, xtragrid

Explanation:

I have an grid view which contains RepositoryItemCheckEdit column's and RepositoryItemTextEdit column's,grid view contains column's like `Item Id`, `Bar code`,`Pack Id` etc

**1)RepositoryItemCheckEdit**

Same `Item Id` and `bar code` can come multiple items in grid view with different `pack id`.

What I need is, if user selects any one item id's check box in grid view means i need all associated check box row's to be checked or unchecked viceversa. User may select either first check box or last check box then associated check box need to be checked or unchecked viceversa based upon user selection

**2)RepositoryItemTextEdit**

Same as like check box Column Edit,Text edit Column Edit need to be worked such as if user enters 100 in item id column cell value means then corresponding Item id row's should also be assigned as 100 as follows

```
 void repchkCheckbox_CellValueChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
    {
                DataTable dt_check = new DataTable();
                dt_check = (DataTable)gcItemMaster.DataSource;
                Int64 sItemId = Convert.ToInt64(gvItemMaster.GetRowCellValue(gvItemMaster.FocusedRowHandle, gvItemMaster.Columns["ItemID"]));
                bool bDiscount = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);
                int iItemcount = (from DataRow row in dt_check.Rows where (string)row["ItemID"] == "1" select row).Count();
                int iRowHandle = gvItemMaster.FocusedRowHandle;
                for (int i = 0; i < iItemcount; i++)
                {
                    if (bDiscount)
                        gvItemMaster.SetRowCellValue(iRowHandle, gvItemMaster.Columns["AllowDiscount"], true);
                    else
                        gvItemMaster.SetRowCellValue(iRowHandle, gvItemMaster.Columns["AllowDiscount"], false);

                    iRowHandle++;
                }
         }
```

Illustrative Purpose : if i contains 5 rows in gridview with same itemid but different packid...
    if i check very first row checkbox of itemId means i can easily able to populate remaining checkbox like 2nd,3rd,4th,5th through increamenting rowhandle value 
   But My Question is if suppose i check 3 row of gridview Itemid checkbox means i can able to populate only 4th and 5th row of checkbox state..but 1st and 2nd row remains the same...

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Any efforts? What problems have you faced?

Comment: Sorry cant see any explained problem you had while implementing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the Solution It's works Perfectly:

```
                     Int64 iItemId = Convert.ToInt64(gvItemMaster.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "ItemID"));
                     bool bDiscount = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);

                for (int i = 0; i < gvItemMaster.DataRowCount; i++)
                {
                    Int64 id = Convert.ToInt64(gvItemMaster.GetRowCellValue(i, "ItemID"));
                    if (id == iItemId)
                    {
                        if (bDiscount)
                            gvItemMaster.SetRowCellValue(i, gvItemMaster.Columns[""+sColumn.Replace(" ","")+""], true);
                        else
                            gvItemMaster.SetRowCellValue(i, gvItemMaster.Columns[""+sColumn.Replace(" ","")+""], false);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a field in your data table to represent the checked state?

If you do then you don't actually need to go via the grid. You can simply select the rows with a matching ID from the data table and set the relevant column to the value you want for each of those data rows. The change will automatically be reflected in the grid.